# Plotly plot_trisurf isn't working with arange arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've basically just copied the example code found on the Matplotlib website, but I replaced their radii and angles with simple arange arrays.

I've tried different array functions and I can't seem to figure out anything.

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from Equation import Expression


x = np.arange(0,100,0.01)
y = np.arange(0,100,0.01)
x2 = np.append(0,x.flatten())
y2 = np.append(0,y.flatten())
z = x2 + y2
print(z)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, linewidth=0.2, antialiased=True)
plt.show()
```

I'm just trying to make a graph of `z = x + y` but I'm getting a confusing error.

> "RuntimeError: Error in qhull Delaunay triangulation calculation: singular input data (exitcode=2); use python verbose option (-v) to see original qhull error."

Edit: I've also tried it without calling `flatten()` but I get the same result though.

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting is because your `z` is not a surface but a line. You need to use at least 3 points that would define a plane. One option could be to use np.meshgrid to create your surface for plotting and then flatten everything to insert into the function. Try going back to some example code [here](https://plot.ly/python/trisurf/). Note you may also want to change your resolution depending on the detail of your surface.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.arange(0,100,1)
y = np.arange(0,100,1)
x2 = np.append(0,x.flatten())
y2 = np.append(0,y.flatten())

x2,y2 = np.meshgrid(x2,y2) #This is what you were missing

z = x2 + y2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x2.flatten(), y2.flatten(), z.flatten(), linewidth=0.2, antialiased=True) #flatten all the arrays here


plt.show()
```

[image]